# React Native IOS build clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, react-native

While I'm trying to run the react-native ios application with command react-native run-ios. The Build goes failed and showing me error following:-

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/User/Documents/react-test-app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React'
>   ld: library not found for -lRNSVG clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>          Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-test-app.app/react-test-app
>   normal x86_64 (1 failure)
>
> Installing
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-test-app.app An error
>   was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain,
>   code=22): Failed to install the requested application The bundle
>   identifier of the application could not be determined. Ensure that the
>   application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/oldapollo.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist.

Please Help Me Out To resolve this problem.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the solutions here.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308

Possible ones may work

1. Update React using `react-native upgrade`

or

2. Run from the project by opening from your `project.xcworkspace`

Answer (score 0):

Open `Melkana.xcworkspace` instead of `Melkana.xcodeproj` in `Xcode`